# Verificar rota com variável no Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou usando o código abaixo para atribuir a classe "active" quando estiver na rota "produto" ou "produto/create".

```
<li {!! Request::is('produto', 'produto/create')? 'class="active"' : null !!}>
```

Agora preciso fazer o mesmo na edição do produto, sendo que a rota de edição tem uma variável que é o id do produto, como faço pra resolver isso?

Exemplo de rotas:

```
produto/1/edit
produto/7/edit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `Request::is` aceita *wildcards* (`*`) [segundo a documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests).

> The is method allows you to verify that the incoming request URI
>   matches a given pattern. You may use the * character as a wildcard
>   when utilizing this method:
>
> ```
> if ($request->is('admin/*')) {
>     //
> }
> ```

No seu caso, tente o seguinte

```
<li {!! Request::is('produto/*/edit')? 'class="active"' : null !!}>
```

Comment: Show! vlw mano funcionou.